# Oracle Procedure with out parameter and ArrayBindCount/ArrayBindSize

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, plsql, procedure

I am testing a simple Oracle procedure and somehow I am getting an error, which I couldn't see why.

```
using (var dbConnection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KWC"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var command = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    var data = new List<Tuple<int, string, string, string>>
                    {
                        Tuple.Create(1, "hello", "kitty", "empty1"),
                        Tuple.Create(2, "mike", "perry", "empty2")
                    };

                    int listCount = data.Count;
                    command.CommandText = "KWC_Test_Output";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.BindByName = true;
                    command.ArrayBindCount = listCount;

                    command.Parameters.Add("string1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, data.Select(t=>t.Item2).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                    command.Parameters.Add("string2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, data.Select(t=>t.Item3).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                    var returnParam = new OracleParameter("result", OracleDbType.Varchar2, null, ParameterDirection.Output) { ArrayBindSize = new int[2] { 255, 255 } };
                    command.Parameters.Add(returnParam);

                    //command.Parameters[2].ArrayBindSize = new int[data.Count()];
                    //command.Parameters[2].ArrayBindSize[0] = 100;
                    //command.Parameters[2].ArrayBindSize[1] = 100;

                    var myParams = command.Parameters; // for debugging

                    dbConnection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // gets exception here

                    Console.WriteLine("returned value from oracle procedure: " + command.Parameters["result"].Value);
                }
            }
```

The error I got was:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-06550: linje 1, kolonne 7:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'KWC_TEST_OUTPUT'
>   ORA-06550: linje 1, kolonne 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored'

And here is the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE KWC_Test_Output(p_string1 IN VARCHAR2, p_string2 IN VARCHAR2, result OUT VARCHAR2)
  AS
  BEGIN
    IF p_string1 = 'exception' THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_string1);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_string2);
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
    ELSE
        result := CONCAT(p_string1, p_string2);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(result);
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        result := SQLERRM;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(result);
END KWC_Test_Output;
```

Can someone tell me why it is failing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I'm reading you code correctly (not sure) it looks like 3rd parameter (return parameter) in the script int INTEGER array, while the plsql procedure is expecting STRING (varchar2). Also the format as integer array as in plsql that would require a collection type.

Comment: The 3rd parameter is null. The array you see is the configuration for the binding.

Comment: I wonder if I should use PL/SQL Assosiative Array.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an array would be a possibility providing you have a suitable TYPE definition for it.

```
create type kwc_result is table of varchar2(100); 
create or replace procedure kwc_test_output(
          p_string1 in varchar2
        , p_string2 in varchar2
        , result   out kwc_result
        )
  as 
  ...  
end kwc_test_output;
```

I guess in Oracle terms that's actually a nested table. But as your procedure is currently constructed that's not necessary, a simple string is sufficient. I guess it could be e stripped down version for demo purposes.